# Beautiful Soup AttributeError

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

for n in range(1, 16):
    response = requests.get(
        'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=books&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as'
        '=off '
        '&page=' + str(n))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # print(soup.prettify())

    urls = list()

    for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class': '_2cLu-l'}):
        urls.append('https://www.flipkart.com' + a['href'])

    # for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class': '_31qSD5'}):
    #     urls.append('https://www.flipkart.com' + a['href'])
    #
    # for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class': '_3dqZjq'}):
    #     urls.append('https://www.flipkart.com' + a['href'])

    products = list()

    for url in urls:
        product = dict()
        page_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')

        name = page_soup.find('h1', {'class': '_9E25nV'})
        product['name'] = name.text

        price = page_soup.find('div', {'class': '_1vC4OE _3qQ9m1'})
        product['price'] = price.text

        ratingsAndReviews = page_soup.find('span', {'class': '_38sUEc'})

        if ratingsAndReviews is None:
            product['ratingsAndReviews'] = '0 ratings & 0 reviews'
        else:
            product['ratingsAndReviews'] = ratingsAndReviews.text

        products.append(product)

        df = pd.DataFrame(products)
        print(df)
        df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\shiva\Desktop\Damn\Output_flipkart.csv', index=True)
```

**product['name'] = name.text | AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the website throws unwanted html in order to block you. So, put a `try/except` block in inner for loop. In that way even if you some urls don't work, it won't stop the program.

And put the code to convert to dataframe and saving out of the for loops

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

products = list()

for n in range(1, 16):
    response = requests.get(
        'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=books&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as'
        '=off '
        '&page=' + str(n))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    urls = list()
    
    for a in soup.find_all('a', {'class': '_2cLu-l'}):
        urls.append('https://www.flipkart.com' + a['href'])

    for url in urls:
        try:
            product = dict()
            res = requests.get(url)

            page_soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
            name = page_soup.find('h1', {'class': '_9E25nV'})
            product['name'] = name.text

            price = page_soup.find('div', {'class': '_1vC4OE _3qQ9m1'})
            product['price'] = price.text

            ratingsAndReviews = page_soup.find('span', {'class': '_38sUEc'})

            if ratingsAndReviews is None:
                product['ratingsAndReviews'] = '0 ratings & 0 reviews'
            else:
                product['ratingsAndReviews'] = ratingsAndReviews.text

            products.append(product)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

df = pd.DataFrame(products)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: I have to keep the df in for, if it is kept outside only items of the first page are retrieved.

Comment: No, you don't have to because you are appending the data to the `products` list

Comment: Yes, you are right! My bad, I'm new to python

Comment: the issue is that in the CSV it is only populating 39 fields, I am not able to understand why, because while printing the df it retrieves data for all 15 WebPages but CSV is populated only for the 1st WebPage. Is there an issue with indentation? I am using the code given by you.

Comment: @ShivamMagotra Most of the pages would have got exception. Re-run the updated script

Comment: Still only the first page data is printed in the CSV  *:'(* . Please can you run it  on your machine or is there a way I can send you the CSV .

Comment: @ShivamMagotra Found the issue, `products` variable should be a global variable. Updated the script

Comment: Yes, that was the issue and the script works well now. Thanks!